# Referring to CTE in WHERE condition of UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to run a query like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM t1 GROUP BY id, category
)
UPDATE table SET amount = cte.sum_amount WHERE id = cte.id;
```

However, I keep getting the error

```
Unknown column 'cte.id in WHERE clause'
```

Does anyone know how I can refer to my common table expression in the UPDATE query, or otherwise, rewrite it?

Comment: I would do like `(SELECT id from cte)` but not sure about CTE, give a try!

Comment: The cte's select is a bit odd. You select id, but group by category. Execute it stand-alone and see if it really returns what you want.

Comment: As @jarlh said it's not event valid query to get the result from CTE!

Comment: @Lockheed have updated an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM t1 GROUP BY category
)
UPDATE T
SET  T.sum_amount= CT.sum_amount
FROM table T
JOIN cte CT
     ON T.id = CT.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way with Temporary table, you can read about [CTE and Temporary Table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117)

Temporary table:

```
SELECT id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
INTO #temp
FROM t1 GROUP BY id, category
```

Update query with temp table:

```
UPDATE OT
SET  OT.sum_amount= TT.sum_amount
FROM table OT
JOIN #temp TT
    ON OT.id = TT.id
```

CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT id, category, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM t1 GROUP BY id,category
)
UPDATE T
SET T.sum_amount= CT.sum_amount
FROM table T
JOIN cte CT
    ON T.id = CT.id
```